# Certain text always included in new document

Tags: document-classes, preamble

Is there a way to make `\documentclass` and all that to always appear in a new document? It's annoying to have to copy from other documents.

Comment: You can create a `template.tex` that has the standard preamble you use.  Then you can open that and resave it as `name.tex`.

Answer (score 5):

You can contain your *entire* preamble (`\documentclass` included) in a separate file, say `file.tex`, which you then `\input` before the `document` environment. For example,

#### `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
```

#### `myfile.tex`:

```
\input{file}% Input common document class & preamble
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]